# MkvMerge add Chapters for each File

Tags: bash, mkv

I'm trying to do something I think SHOULD be pretty straightforward, but can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

In MKVMerge I want to merge a number of files, and at the end/beginning of each file, insert a chapter break in the new file. Preferably with the name of the next file, but thats not critical.

I've been trying to dynamically generate a chapter file, but adding up timecodes in bash is proving to be VERY difficult, and I don't see any other way to do it as of now

Comment: For those people not familiar with `MKVMerge` it would be useful if you included some more details about what you are doing, what you need to be doing, what you are trying to do, etc. Showing us the code/commands you have/are trying would be good as a general idea as well.

Comment: You can use `date(1)` to add time. Or you can always write your own functions, but beware that bash is not very good at floating point arithmetic. Your best bet is a more powerful scripting language, e.g., Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. From the [`mkmerge` documentation, § "2.3. Chapter and tag handling (global options)"](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#d4e222):

> `--generate-chapters` *mode*
>
> - '`when-appending`' – This mode creates one chapter at the start and one chapter whenever a file is appended.

For example:

```
mkvmerge -o concatenated.mkv --generate-chapters when-appending 1.mp4 + 2.mp4 + 3.mp4 + …
```